# Tab Activity is not working

Tags: android, tabs

Hi I have created a simple tab activity , and it is not working , I need some assistance here , I know I have done some stupid mistake somewhere ..please help guys ..
giving my logcat below

```
10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                       
activity ComponentInfo{com.friendfinder/com.friendfinder.TabActivityLayouts}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.

10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at  
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

 10-28 03:44:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):    at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

**giving my tab activity class below..**

```
            public class TabActivityLayouts extends TabActivity{


        @Override   
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_form);

    TabHost tabhost= getTabHost();

    TabSpec spec=tabhost.newTabSpec("Welcome");     
    spec.setIndicator("w", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_tab1));
    Intent in=new Intent(this,WelcomeTabActivity.class);
    spec.setContent(in);

    TabSpec specific=tabhost.newTabSpec("Friends");
    spec.setIndicator("s", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_tab2));
    Intent i=new Intent(this,FriendsListTabActivity.class);
    spec.setContent(i);

    tabhost.addTab(spec);
    tabhost.addTab(specific);
         }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your second tab in which you have wrongly set the indicator instance to `specific` instead of `spec` in your last tab.

Instead of as below:

```
TabSpec specific=tabhost.newTabSpec("Friends");
spec.setIndicator("s", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_tab2)); //Change the instance here.
Intent i=new Intent(this,FriendsListTabActivity.class);
spec.setContent(i);
```

Do as below:

```
TabSpec specific=tabhost.newTabSpec("Friends");
specific.setIndicator("s", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_tab2));
 Intent i=new Intent(this,FriendsListTabActivity.class);
specific.setContent(i);
```